# Desktop launch icon "there was an error launching the application"

Tags: 16.04, .desktop

I created the following .desktop item for launching MySQL Workbench:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.99
Name=MSWB
Comment=MySQL Workbench
Exec=/usr/bin/mysql-workbench
Icon=/home/steve/Pictures/mswb.png
Terminal=false
Type=application
Categories=application
```

The owner is root and the permissions are

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  root   183 May 18 15:49 mswb.desktop
```

When I double click the icon I get "there was an error launching the application."  There is nothing in the log.  Following the advice on another thread, I issued this from a terminal window

```
awk -F= '/Exec=/{system($2)}' mswb.desktop
```

and the program started right up.  Any idea how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .desktop file for MySQL Workbench already exists in /usr/share/applications. Here it is...

```
$ more mysql-workbench.desktop [Desktop Entry]
Name=MySQL Workbench
Comment=MySQL Database Design, Administration and Development Tool
Exec=mysql-workbench
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=mysql-workbench
MimeType=application/vnd.mysql-workbench-model;
Categories=GTK;Database;Development;
StartupWMClass=mysql-workbench-bin
```